# go - Get time from RethinkDB

Tags: javascript, time, go, utc, rethinkdb

I have a struct `Quote` in Go

```
type Quote struct{
    CreatedAt int64 `gorethink:"createdAt"`
    // Other fields...
}
```

I write to query data from RethinkDB and succeed

```
result,err:=r.Table("quote").GetAll(ids...).Run(session)

defer result.Close()

        if err!=nil{
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
        var quotes []Quote
        err=result.All(&quotes)
```

It does get true results, but none of records has value in `CreatedAt` field. The time format I use for `createdAt` in database is milliseconds since epoch UTC, I intend to use them as number to calculate after

I read GoDocs for time and found:

`func (t Time) Unix() int64`

So I thought `int64` would be the right type for `CreatedAt`, but it didn't work. What should I do? How can I get time data?

`time.Time` doesn't work as well. If `time.Time` is used, the result is always `0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC` (similarly `0` value if converted to milliseconds)

Because when I built the same server in NodeJS I used `Date.Now()`, I need to seek an equivalent type in this case, which returns a number for me to calculate later process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find the answer myself. True type is used in this condition is `float64` so that results fetched match with in database explorer (for example, `1458184908597` milliseconds)

Answer (score 3):

When using [gorethink](https://github.com/dancannon/gorethink) the driver will automatically convert to and from GO’s native data types. Change your struct to use `time.Time`:

```
type Quote struct{
    CreatedAt   time.Time  `gorethink:"created_at"`
}
```

For more samples you can check the respective [test cases](https://github.com/dancannon/gorethink/blob/master/query_time_test.go).

Comment: Before I decided to change type to `int64`, I declared it with type `time.Time` and it didn't work. Now it definitely does not work as well

Comment: Result is always `0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC` (if converted to milliseconds, it is `0`)

Comment: if you are working with time use `time.Time` if you want the ms of it you would do something like `Quote.CreatedAt.Unix()` note that the `func (t Time) Unix() int64` is a function of (`time.Time`) with the name `Unix(no params)` and returns `int64`